# Passing function into super constructor

Tags: dart

How would I go about doing something like this:

```dart
class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    List<String> text = [];

    factory SubClass(bool debug) {
        var func = (info) { if (debug) text.add(info); }
        return SubClass._internal(func);
    }

    SubClass._internal(func) : super(func);
}
```

I can't figure out how to implement it, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that the best solution was to implement the class and use delegation to simulate the function.

```dart
class SubClass implements SuperClass {
  Function _f; // dummy variable
  SuperClass _delegate;

  f(text) => _delegate.f(text);

  List<String> text = [];

  SubClass(bool debug) {
    var func = (info) { if (debug) text.add(info); };

    _delegate = new SuperClass(func);
  }
}

class SuperClass {
  Function _f;
  f(text) => _f(text);

  SuperClass(this._f);
}

void main() {
  var x = new SubClass(true);
  x.f("info");
  x.f("more info");
  x.text.forEach((e) => print(e));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you define the function in another class you can do the wiring in the factory constructor but only after the instance is created.

(When a class has a call function it can be treated as a function - see `AddDebug` class)
Here a new `AddDebug` class is passed to the constructor and the reference to text is passed after an instance is created. I used the abstract class `TextHolder` as interface.

If you define the function inline it is a static method which can't reference instance members.

Here two solutions how you could do it.
If you comment out the `// alternative` lines you get the second solution

```dart
library x;

class SuperClass {
  Function _f;
  SuperClass(this._f);
  Function get f => _f;

  void set f(Function f) { // alternative
    _f = f;                //
  }                        //
}

abstract class TextHolder {
  List<String> text;
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass implements TextHolder {
  List<String> text = [];

  factory SubClass([bool debug = false])  {
    var ad = new AddDebug(true);
    var nsc = new SubClass._internal(ad);
    ad.textHolder = nsc;

    nsc.f = new AddDebug2(nsc.text, true); // alternative
    return nsc;
  }

  SubClass._internal(func) : super(func);
}


void main(List<String> args) {
  var x = new SubClass(true);
  x.f("sometext");
  x.f("anothertext");
  x.text.forEach((e) => print(e));
}


class AddDebug implements Function {
  bool _debug;
  AddDebug([this._debug = false]);

  TextHolder textHolder;

  call(info) {
    if(_debug) {
      textHolder.text.add(info);
    }
  }
}

// alternative (entire class)
class AddDebug2 implements Function {
  bool _debug;
  AddDebug2(this._text, [this._debug = false]);

  List<String> _text;

  call(info) {
    if(_debug) {
      _text.add(info);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just seems like syntax errors to me, try this, i added a semicolon and `new`

```dart
class SubClass extends SuperClass {
  List<String> text = [];

  factory SubClass(bool debug) {
    var func = (info) { if (debug) text.add(info); };    
    return new SubClass._internal(func);
  }

  SubClass._internal(func) : super(func);
}
```

Comment: The problem is more subtile. The factory constructor can't access the member `test` of an object it has yet to create.